# Why Autoboxed Integer isn't incremented inside the caller

Tags: java, parameters, pass-by-reference, autoboxing

Consider the code:

```
static void incr(Integer n)
{
    n++;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
   Integer n = 66; // Autoboxing

   incr(n);

   System.out.println(n);
}
```

The above program outputs 66. I expected it to print 67 and here is why. Boxing a value converts the primitive value to an object, right. In case of objects, Java passes the pointer to the object to a called function, that's incr in the above example. incr() increments the value in the memory cell passed to it. So, the change in value must occur in n too. Now please tell me, what am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: `incr` does _not_ increment the value in the memory cell passed to it.  It changes the reference to point to a new cell with a value one higher than the value in the cell that was passed to it.  `Integer` is immutable; you just made `n` point to a new, higher value.

Comment: `Integer`s are immutable. You can't change their `int` value, for a very good reason.